# Find 3rd point of triangle knowing A and B coordinates and all the angles

Tags: triangles

I got a triangle, knowing A and B coordinates and all the three angles, how can I calculate C coordinates?

[image]
[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1VM6.jpg)

Comment: Calculate the distance $AB$ and then use the sine-rule to calculate the other  lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a post that understandable for the noob that I am ^^

[Answering post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725790/calculate-third-point-of-triangle-from-two-points-and-angles)

> x1=0;y1=0;x2=6;y2=0; % initial data
>
> alp1=2*pi/3;alp2=pi/6; % initial data
>
> u=x2-x1;v=y2-y1;a3=sqrt(u^2+v^2);
>
> alp3=pi-alp1-alp2;
>
> a2=a3*sin(alp2)/sin(alp3);
>
> RHS1=x1*u+y1*v+a2*a3*cos(alp1);
>
> RHS2=y2*u-x2*v+a2*a3*sin(alp1);
>
> x3=(1/a3^2)*(u*RHS1-v*RHS2);
>
> y3=(1/a3^2)*(v*RHS1+u*RHS2);

Comment: You also could have asked a while ago that you need clarification. In my opinion, it should be your goal do unterstand why things work, not only how. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let 
\begin{align*}
R_\alpha:=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha &\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
be the rotation matrix which rotates a vector around the origin in anti-clockwise direction by the angle $\alpha$ (given in rad).

Let $\alpha$ be the angle $CAB$ at $A$, and let $\beta$ be the angle $ABC$ at $B$. Now, $C$ is the intersection of the line from $A$ to $B$ rotated by $-\alpha$ and of the line from $B$ to $A$ rotated by $\beta$. Thus, $C$ satisfies the system of 4 linear equations:
\begin{align}
C&=A+xR_{-\alpha}(B-A), &(1) \\
C&=B+yR_\beta(A-B).     &(2)
\end{align}
These equations are equivalent to the system of 2 linear equations
\begin{align*}
&(I-xR_{-\alpha}-yR_\beta)(A-B)=0. &(3)
\end{align*}
Now, just solve these two equations for $x$ or $y$ (it doesn't matter) and then put this in (1) or (2) to get $C$.

**Example:** Let $A=(1,4),B=(2,1),\alpha=1.5,\beta=0.5.$ Then $(A-B)=(-1,3)$ and $(3)$ reads
\begin{align*}
-2.92175 x+2.31586 y&=1, \\
-1.20971 x-2.15332 y&=-3.
\end{align*}
The solution is $x=0.527248, y=1.097$, which gives $C=(-0.540487,3.36218)$.
[image]